# How to get sum of parent association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In my Rails 3.2.8 application, I'm trying to calculate all of the users products and tax amount in total. It should get the total of the Products and then the Tax on each product.

```
class Product
  attr_accessible :amount, :location_id, :tax_id
  belongs_to :tax
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :tax, :class_name => "Tax"

  def self.total
    self.sum(:amount) + self.tax.sum(:amount)
  end
end
```

**Tax.rb**

```
class Tax < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :amount, :date, :location_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :location
  has_many :products
end
```

So when I try a scope like this:

```
<%= number_to_currency(current_user.products.total) %>
```

This of course gives me an error:

```
undefined method `tax' for #<Class:0x57f5298>
```

How can I write this to make it work?

Thank you.

Comment: you're mixing class and instance attributes/methods

Comment: Why do you have tax as a related object? Why not have tax as an attribute on product?

Comment: Can you post the relevant Tax class source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tax` is a Product's instance method, not of class Product

try the following (weak performance):

```
class Product
  belongs_to :tax

  def self.total
    self.sum(:amount) + all.map(&:tax).map(&:amount).sum
  end
end
```

Comment: Weird. I had to upgrade to rails 3.2.8 and then it started to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not great with ActiveRecord's newer query methods. I guest I'm a little old fashioned and have a tendency to lean more towards SQL, but this should "efficiently" get what you want.

```
  def self.total
    self.select('sum(products.amount + taxes.amount) AS sum').joins(:tax).try(:sum, 0)
  end
```

Comment: That actually made it come back blank. Also, why have products and not just `amount + tax.amount`? This didn't work either for me even when I did try.

Answer (score 1):

From this line

```
<%= number_to_currency(current_user.products.total) %>
```

I understood that for current user you need the sum from his products and taxes.
What you have done before is not related to the current user but to the whole table of products instead, and of course some product in this table can be not related to the current user.

So here's what I think how it might be.

```
#Instance method for current user
class User < ...
  def product_tax_total
    products.joins(:tax).select('SUM(products.amount + taxes.amount) AS sum').sum
  end
end
```

And use it like this:

```
<%= number_to_currency(current_user.product_tax_total) %>
```

Update:

You can use scope to chain the queries:

```
class Product
  scope :today, lambda { where(:date => Date.today) }
end
```

And then chain it

```
class User < ...
  def product_tax_total
    products.today.joins(:tax).select('SUM(products.amount + taxes.amount) AS sum').sum
  end
end
```

Comment: Not sure why this didn't work. It gave me an argument error. Also it might be difficult to use this because I have other methods that go with this method such as `def self.today
    where(:date => Date.today)
  end`. I have a `date` column with products too. This is why I try to keep it inside of the `Product` class.

Comment: Share your code on github for example to understand what is really going on.

Comment: Ok cool but I still get the `wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)`. The trace for the first 2 lines says: `lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:149:in 'calculate'
activerecord (3.2.8)`, `lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:96:in 'sum'`

Comment: Remove '.sum' from the end and explore the result of the sql query by  the explain command http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#running-explain

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16145/discussion-between-megas-and-learningror)